# When to call the update() on widgets?

Tags: c++, qt4

When does the [update()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#update) method needs to be called?

Do I have to call it at all?

All I am doing with my widgets are [setGeometry()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#geometry-prop) and [raise()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#raise).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setGeometry()` and `raise()` should automatically cause a `paintEvent` on the corresponding widgets.

I think most of Qt's own widgets call `update()` where appropriate. On custom widgets you call `update()` whenever something that is visible changes. For example, if you have your own Label class (that does not inherit from `QLabel` and hence does not use `QLabel`'s facilities to change text and/or image), you call `update()` whenever you change the content, such that the new content will be displayed on screen.

Beware: You should not use `repaint()` on widgets if the repainting is not really time critical. `repaint()` causes a `paintEvent` to be issued to the widget at the moment it is called, whereas `update()` just queues a `paintEvent` to be issued the next time the process reaches the main loop. This allows the paint engine to collect several `paintEvent`s for the same widget and issue just one combined event. Using `repaint()` can thus really impact performance.